# Django - filter queryset until Sum is reached

Tags: python, django, sum, annotations

Let's imagine a model called `Roll`. It stores the outcome of rolling a six-sided die (D6):

```
class Roll(models.Model):
    outcome = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Roll', null=False, blank=False, default=1)
```

There are many rolls, for example:

```
print(list(Roll.objects.all().values_list('outcome', flat=True)))
>>> [1, 5, 6, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2]
```

Now, how should I go about to get the latest N rows whose Sum('outcome') reaches an arbitrary amount, without looping in some way or another, until that amount is reached?

If we imagine the rolls:

```
pk    | outcome | (accumulated sum)
1     | 3       | 3
2     | 2       | 5
3     | 6       | 11
4     | 1       | 12
5     | 5       | 17
6     | 4       | 21
7     | 3       | 24
8     | 4       | 29
9     | 5       | 34
10    | 1       | 35
```

and the arbitrary amount `20`, then the query should pick the pk `6` as the accumulated sum has now reached the amount needed.

Could something similar to the below work?:

```
amount = 100
Roll.objects.annotate(
    accumulated_sum=Subquery(
        Roll.objects.filter(
            pk__lte=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('pk').order_by('pk').annotate(
            sum=Sum('outcome', distinct=True)
        ).values(
            'sum'
        )[:1]
    )
).filter(
    accumulated_sum__gte=amount
)
```

Comment: Are you having issue annotating accumulated_sum?

Comment: apparently yes :-)

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: mysql 8.x (+min text padding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help annotating accumuated_sum:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, IntegerField

class SQSum(Subquery):
    output_field = IntegerField()
    template = "(SELECT sum(outcome) from (%(subquery)s) _sum)"

accumulated_subquery = SQSum(
    Roll.objects.filter(
        pk__lte=OuterRef('pk')
    ).values("outcome")
)

Roll.objects.annotate(accumulated_sum=accumulated_subquery).filter(accumulated_sum__gte=amount)
```

Comment: thanks -- any way to get the same result without subclassing `Subquery`?

Comment: No Sorry. Don't have any other way. Are you having some issue with Subquery?